# Media queries not working in IE8 - even with respond.js work-around

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

My site consists of 5 divs (represented by green boxes). There should be
3 per row, and you can view my demo site here: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo.html

IE 8 doesn't support media queries, but I'm using respond.js as a work-around. I can't get it to work though.

the media queries I'm using are:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1320px){

.block{
    width: 45%;    
    margin: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 670px;
    max-height: 670px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
/*    border: 1px solid red;*/
}
   }
        @media screen and (max-width: 772px){

    .block{
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 710px;
    max-height: 710px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
/*    border: 1px solid red;*/
}
    }
```

where .block applies to the green div boxes. These work fine except in IE8.

I'm calling on respond.js after all my css, just before the  tag like this:

```
<script src="http://testsite24.netai.net/public/js/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I view the page in IE 8, it doesn't respond to the queries,

here is a screenshot in IE8:

[image: ie8]

and here is one for IE 9 (correct):

[image: ie9]

What's wrong?? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

Put the css in an external file and link to it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/demo.css" />
```

And take out the `only` keyword and change to `min-width`.

```
@media screen 
and (min-width : 773px) { 
    //instead of (max-width:1320px)
}
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'm still having issues though: I updated my demo code to include  

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 773px) 
and (max-width : 1320px) {
 
 .block{
    ***STYLES HERE****
}
}

and

Comment: and then 

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 10px) 
and (max-width : 772px) {
 
 .block{
    ***STYLES HERE***
}
 }

but IE8 doesn't respond still... You can view my demo source code to ensure I've changed it properly. Thanks so much

Comment: Take out the 's' from beneath the `<title></title>` tag, and try **just** using min-width

Comment: Changed the code, but still not working. The only media query I have now for block is  

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 773px) {
 
 .block{
    width: 45%;    
    margin: 0 15px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 min-height: 670px;
 max-height: 670px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
/*    border: 1px solid red;*/
}
}

.. But it still doesn't respond in IE 8 only. Here's the screenshot for IE8: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/IE82.png . And here's IE9: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/IE92.png

Comment: That seems to work, Ryan. Thanks man. The only thing is that it seems to be applying the smallest media query to ALL viewport sizes. The smallest media query is for 10px,  @media screen 
and (min-width : 10px) { 
 
 .block{
    width: 100%;   
}

but I've also included 
 (at)media screen 
and (min-width : 402px) { 
 
 .block{
    width: 45%;    
    
}}  above it, which seems to be overpowered by the 10px media query. How can I adapt the code to allow for variation? At large viewports I need 3 divs per row. Medium viewports I need 2 per row. Small, 1 per row.  .

Comment: Nevermind, I changed the min-width to max-width and tinkered a bit, and now it works!! Thanks so much Ryan